# Can't retrieve selected item in spinner Android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am retrieving data from the web service and displaying it on the spinner(Android) through an object. When the item is selected and show text view.

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_id);
String selectedText = String.valueOf(sp.getSelectedItem());
tvShow.setText(selectedText);
```

I'm getting the exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: First define tvshow with findviewbyid

Comment: whats the value of `sp.getSelectedItem()` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `spinner` has no `selected item` when you trying to `parse` it to `string`.

To `handle exception` you can try like this

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_id);
if (sp.getSelectedItem() == null) {
    // handle null here
}else {
    String selectedText = String.valueOf(sp.getSelectedItem());
    tvShow.setText(selectedText);
}
```